# How to eliminate the space after the second line?

Tags: css

This is the code:

```
#content{width:400px;}
h2{margin:0px;line-height:100px;}

<div id="content">
    <h2>Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world.</h2>
    <span>goodbyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</span>
</div>
```

[See how the code work here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj3Dn/)

I need a way to put the "goodbyeeeeee.." string 2px below the h2 headline without ( if possible ) using margin with negative numbers ).

Obviously I need also the space between the 2 lines of the h2 headline.

EDIT: I can also avoid to use line-height but I need the space between the 2 lines of the h2 headline.

Comment: You need to 'make up your mind'. First you tell the browser to make all lines 100 pixels high, then you decide not all of them. CSS cannot do that inside an element, so you'll have to resort to negative margins. No reason not to actually, it's a good solution.

Comment: Agreed. Negative margins are the way to go here. That's what they are for, and they work really well.

Comment: I can also don't use line-height but I need the space between the 2 lines of the h2 headline.

Comment: Whatever CSS trick you try, it will look ugly after some text-only zoom (think of 1 line if the text is small enough, 3 lines when big enough). Best way is to split the `H2` text into 2 elements with different margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the height could do it, depending on the situation.

```
h2{margin:0px;line-height:100px;height: 157px;}
```

Comment: This seems the solution, I will test it on other browsers otherwise I will use the negative margin http://jsfiddle.net/Jj3Dn/10/

Comment: That only works properly if you know that your h2 will never wrap.

Comment: Correct. But, since he's not asking for the best way to do it, i'm not supplying that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to change the way `line-height` behaves. It puts the text of the `h2` in the middle of the 100px high line.

So, sorry, but no. Unless you find a way to get rid of the `line-height` property, you're stuck with using negative margins. Or relative positions.

Edit:
If you do use a negative margin, please put in on the `h2` itself, not on any other element that happens to come after it in your current page. The `h2` is causing the problem, so that's where you should solve it.

Comment: I can eliminate the line-height but I need the space between the 2 lines of the h2 headline :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the large spacing between the two lines of the `h2` but want the `span` text hugging the bottom of the second line of the `h2`, you can set the span to `display: block` to enforce the negative margin:

```
h2{margin:0px; line-height:100px;}
span{display: block; margin-top:-40px;}
```